# Website does not render correctly on mobile browser(s) after upload to server

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile

I'm not an expert in web and I composed and updated my website recently. I ran all the test that I could on DreamWeaver CC and tested on multiple mobile devices (tablet, android and iphone); all seems to work fine. Until I uploaded the site to my server, the site start to act weird.

1st problem:
It is a portfolio website with individual pages to corresponding projects. On each project page, the first image on the lightbox has always gone missing; but clicking into the lightbox I can find the missing image (the preview image and the lightbox image share the same source so if the lightbox can find the image it implies that the image is on the server and the path is correct).

2nd problem:
when the browser is shrink below certain size, a toggle menu will replace the content on the header, clicking the toggle menu will show a pop up menu to site links. For some reason, after uploading the site to server, the toggle menu pop up never work.

3rd problem:
The above problem is never apparent on desktop browser(all image shows up correctly; toggle menu works). To make the problem more complicated, I can't confirm if it is device or browser oriented problem. For example, the site works on chrome browser on my iphone and nexus 5(android), but problem occurs on my xperia tablet(android) chrome browser; on my xperia tablet, the site works perfectly on firefox.

Does anybody has any idea what the potential cause to the problem, and perhaps a direction to a solution?

Here's the link to my site: http://www.itsatommy.com

Thank you for your time and look forward to any reply.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me (Google Chrome), you need to use media queries for some certain resolutions. You also need to use some cross browser css tags lide "-webkit, -moz, -o" etc.